# Finding a line number certain text is on

Tags: php

what is the best way to find on which line certain string is on? I know I could iterate though all of the lines, but the catch is that the string being searched might be multiline. Would this be solvable by regex for example?
Thanks

Comment: if you use the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag with preg_match, then your problem is reduced from finding which line a string is on, to finding which line its first character is on.

Comment: It would be easier to work on this problem if you could provide a Test Case...  Perhaps like 15 lines of text, and two example "search strings" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solvable.  First search for the pattern where all the lines are searched at once separated, for example with `\n`'s.  Then count the number of `\n`'s before it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're talking about a file the best way it to iterate:

```
$lines = 0;
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
    $lines++;
    if (stripos($line, $searchWord) !== false) {
        $foundOnLine = $lines;
        break;
    }
}
```

But if it's a string, you could do a little bit of a hack (which finds the text before the match, and then returns the number of matches):

```
$foundOnLine = preg_match_all('#\n#', stristr($string, $searchWord, true), $a);
```

But notice that it will return line `0` for both not-found-in-string and found-on-first-line.  If you want to distinguish them:

```
$found = function($string, $searchWord) {
    $pretext = stristr($string, $searchWord, true);
    $a = null;
    return $pretext === false ? false : preg_match_all('#\n#', $pretext, $a);
}
```

That will return `false` if not found, or `0` if on the first line...

Answer (score 0):

I always try and avoid loops when i can

loopless...

```
function getLine( $haystack, $needle ) {
    return substr_count( substr( $haystack, 0, strpos($haystack, $needle ) ), "\n" ) + 1;
}
```

[working example](http://ideone.com/IL6xz)